# In C++20 when should use `iterator_traits<I>::value_type` and when should I use `iter_value_t`?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

C++20 concepts adds an [alternative way](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iter_t) to access iterator traits. For example `iter_value_t<I>` gives a similar result as `iterator_traits<I>::value_type`.<strike>I have noticed that `iterator_traits` do not appear to work in concept constraints.</strike>
`iter_value_t` works for concepts, but it also works everywhere else.
So my hunch is I should use the newer `iter_value_t` since it works in both contexts.

Is this correct? When should I prefer one or the other?

**EDIT:** I was missing `typename` when using iterator_traits in concept constraints. The concepts gave me the jitters!

Comment: What do you mean, it does not appear to work in concept constraints?

Comment: @Barry I received a compiler error, but looking at the other answer, I may have just missed "typename". Since you asked, I will make a small example of it for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should always use `std::iter_value_t<I>`.

First of all, simply consider the length:

```cpp
std::iter_value_t<I>
```

vs.

```cpp
typename std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type
```

Because `value_type` is a dependent type, you'll need that extra `typename` keyword, so this is *a mouthful*.

Secondly, the former is simply defined in more cases than the latter. You'll typically be taking your iterators by value, so it's probably not a huge issue that you'll run into, but `std::iter_value_t<int*&>` is still `int` while `std::iterator_traits<int*&>::value_type` is not defined. Same for `std::iterator_traits<int* const>::value_type`. That is, `std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type` works but `std::iterator_traits<I const>::value_type` or `std::iterator_traits<I&>::value_type` do not -- that's more that you'll have to write to ensure that you're passing a non-reference, non-cv-qualified type.

There's also a few small other edge cases, like how `std::iter_value_t<std::shared_ptr<int>>` is `int` but `std::iterator_traits<std::shared_ptr<int>>::value_type` is not defined. So if you're writing an algorithm that takes an arbitrary indirectly readable that isn't necessarily an iterator, you can still use it.

So just use the short thing that always works, instead of the much longer thing that sometimes doesn't.

---

Typically, `std::iter_reference_t<I>` is much more useful than `std::iter_value_t<I>`, too.

Answer (score 5):

`iter_value_t<I>` is used to implement algorithms in terms of indirectly readable types. `iterator_traits<I>` is used to implement algorithms in terms of iterators.

Indirectly readable types are types that can be read by applying `operator*`. That includes pointers, smart pointers and iterators. All such types satisfy [`indirectly_readable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/indirectly_readable) concept.

To fully understand the idea behind the `iter_value_t<I>` we need to take a look at it's implementation.

*If `std::iterator_traits<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>` is not specialized, then `std::iter_value_t<T>` is `std::indirectly_readable_traits<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>::value_type`. Otherwise, it is `std::iterator_traits<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>::value_type`.*

You can see that if it is possible it tries to default to iterator_traits but additionally applies `remove_cvref_t` transformation to the types. This allows it to work with const-volatile-reference qualified types such as `const char* const` or `const char*&` etc.

> Is this correct?

No, `iterator_traits<I>` work with concepts as well (unless I misunderstood what you've meant by that).

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>

template<class T>
concept my_iterator_concept = 
    std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type, int>;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << my_iterator_concept<typename decltype(v)::iterator>;
}
```

Run the code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/o93WsfYhq).

> When should I prefer one or the other?

Unless (unlikely) you have a specific need for some `iterator_traits` features, use `iter_value_t<T>` together with other members of it's family such as [`iter_reference_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iter_t) or [`iter_difference_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iter_t).

Here is an example why you should prefer it. This is a [`deduction guide for basic_string view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/deduction_guides).

```cpp
template<class It, class End>
basic_string_view(It, End) -> basic_string_view<iter_value_t<It>>;
```

You might want to pass just a `const char* const` as an alternative to iterators like so:

```cpp
// Requires c++ 20
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const char* const c = "example";
    auto str = std::string_view(c, c + 3);
    std::cout << str;
}
```

`iterator_traits<I>::value_type` would fail in this case.
Run the code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/sezGq34jf).

The concept of indirectly readable traits and iterator traits are explained next to each other in the standard and can be found in ([c++23 n4892 working draft](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/n4892.pdf)):

[*23.3.2.2 Indirectly readable traits*](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/n4892.pdf)

[*23.3.2.3 Iterator traits*](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/n4892.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for such elaborate answer! I found that `std::iterator_traits` does not work with `std::ranges::iota` for some integer types, but `iter_value_t` is fine: https://godbolt.org/z/3a86xrsYn